# Are all matrix groups Lie groups?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

I am reading *Lectures on Lie Groups and Lie Algebras*, and I come across the statement on page 50 that says "All matrix groups are Lie groups". Does it mean all subgroups of general linear groups? If it does, how do I prove it?

Comment: Certainly "matrix group" cannot denote *any* subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ in that case, since that would include things like $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: It depends on what the author means by “matrix group.” What is true is that all *closed* subgroups of the general linear groups are Lie groups: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-subgroup_theorem

Comment: thanks, I get it now

Comment: @Kajelad: Actually, as an abstract group, ${\mathbb Q}$ is isomorphic to a Lie group (just equip it with the discrete topology).

Comment: I suppose I should be more precise and say that not every subgroup of $GL(n\mathbb{R})$ can be given the structure of a Lie *subgroup*. I'm not aware of any algebraic subgroups which do not carry *any* Lie structure.

Comment: @Kajelad: Yes, there are such subgroups, see below.

Comment: @henryz: Note that in that book the definition of matrix group is given as: **The orthogonal group is an example of a matrix group, i.e. _a closed subgroup of the group $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ of invertible real $n \times n$ matrices._** So the definition is closed subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authors clearly goofed. There are even examples of matrix groups which are not isomorphic to Lie groups as *abstract groups.* (In the theory of topological groups one usually uses homeomorphic isomorphisms. When I say that an isomorphism of topological groups is *abstract*, I mean that it is a purely group-theoretic isomorphism, which is not required to be continuous.)

For instance, the additive group $\widehat{{\mathbb Z}}_p$ of p-adic integers is isomorphic to a subgroup $G$ of the additive group of real numbers ${\mathbb R}$. This isomorphism can be seen as follows. The algebraic closure $\overline{{\mathbb Q}_p}$ of the field of $p$-adic numbers is isomorphic (as a field) to ${\mathbb C}$. This gives an embedding (as an abstract group) of $\widehat{{\mathbb Z}}_p$ in the additive group of complex numbers. The latter is isomorphic (as an abstract group) to the additive group of real numbers.

One can show that the additive group $\widehat{{\mathbb Z}}_p$ is not isomorphic (as an abstract group) to any Lie group. (My definition of a Lie group includes the 2nd countable assumption.) The key is that $\widehat{{\mathbb Z}}_p$ is a [profinite group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group#Examples), which implies that every nontrivial subgroup of $\widehat{{\mathbb Z}}_p$ has an epimorphism to a nontrivial finite (cyclic) group. At the same time, if $H$ is a connected abelian Lie group, $H$ does not admit (even discontinuous) epimorphisms to finite nontrivial groups. Since $\widehat{{\mathbb Z}}_p$ is uncountable, no subgroup of countable index in it is isomorphic to a Lie group. However, every Lie group contains a connected Lie subgroup of countable index. Thus, $\widehat{{\mathbb Z}}_p$ is not isomorphic to any Lie group (as an abstract group).

Comment: I will wear the down-vote on this answer as a badge of honor.

Comment: (Just for clarification that I am not downvoter nor upvoter.) A famous counterexample is $\widetilde{SL_2(\mathbb{R})}$ I think. Note that in that book the definition of matrix group is given as: **The orthogonal group is an example of a matrix group, i.e. _a closed subgroup of the group $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ of invertible real $n \times n$ matrices._**

Comment: It depends on the meaning of the word "is": In your quote it means "$\tilde{SL}_2(R)$ is not isomorphic as a topological group to any matrix group." In my answer I was talking about isomorphism as an abstract group.